# Child theme not being picked up on product detail page

Tags: magento-1, parent-child-theme, magento1.9.2.4

I'm using Porto theme. I have created a child theme and its working everywhere but the product detail pages.

On those pages it falls back to the default porto theme for all of its templates.

For example there is a template file that is in all pages: `/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto_childtheme/template/page/html/header_type3.phtml` but on the product detail page it's not using that child theme template, the first one it see is `/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/page/html/header_type3.phtml`. There are also css amends I've made in a copy of `layout.xml` in the child theme.

I don't have any exceptions set up:

[image]

I have turned on the debug template path hints and I can see that there is no mention of the child theme in any of its normal places.

I have turned off all caching.

The site works with my child theme throughout the site except on the product detail pages. On these product detail pages the theme default "header_type3.phtml" is being loaded from "porto" instead of "porto_childtheme", the customisations I have made in local.xml to add css files are being skipped, it's like the child theme isn't being checked first.

Is there a setting that could make the product detail templates some kind of special case when selecting the template files?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that certain products had custom designs set up.

To fix the problem:

1. Go to admin > Catalog > Manage Products
2. Find the product that’s not displaying correctly
3. Go to the Design tab and then reset the Custom Design option back to “-- Please Select --" and press Save.

Repeat for each product and then flush caches.

Thanks to this thread - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/67053/48154